# How can reload the content of template after an ajax call in smarty?

Tags: php, ajax, smarty

I am using smarty to build a project in php.  i have created templates containing information of users, now i have to apply filters on users, for this i have called ajax function through javascript and on php page again assigned the smarty variable with new list of users but still i am getting the same user list on page after successful call of ajax function. i.e. template is not reloading with new list of users. i have not much idea about php and smarty so please guide me how can i do this?

Here is the code for ajax call

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "userDetails.php", 
data: { searchKeyWord:searchKeyWord}, success: SearchSucceeded, error:SearchFailed });
```

while in the template we have smarty variable userList that is being assigned from php page.

```
~section name=co loop=$userList` <label id="name" name="Name" size="1" class="productName" style="float:none">~$userList[co].Name` </label<br/><br/>     ~/section`
```

Comment: You might want to provide some relevant code so that we can help you.

Comment: Here is the code for ajax call  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "userDetails.php",
                    data: { searchKeyWord:searchKeyWord},
                    success: SearchSucceeded,
                    error:SearchFailed
                }); while in the template we have smarty variable userList that is being assigned from php page. ~section name=co loop=$userList`         <label id="name" name="Name"
                                             size="1" class="productName" style="float:none">~$userList[co].Name`
</label<br/><br/>          ~/section`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try entering the full URL:

$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: **"http://[domain/path]/** userDetails.php",

Comment: i am able to call ajax service successfully but template is not binding again with new userList assigned to the smarty variables.

Comment: try replacing: data: { searchKeyWord:searchKeyWord} with data: { "searchKeyWord":searchKeyWord}

Comment: see i wanted to implemented searching. and i am passing search keyword through ajax call, first time when page is loading all users should bind but when i entering some keyword they only that users should bind into the template. but it is not happening right now, ajax function is being called successfully but smarty variable that is binding the users details is not reassigning..

Comment: yes, but I believe that you are passing the **value** of the search word twice: both as the key and  as the value!

Comment: though i have wrote it twice but it will not create any problem, i  have made several calls like this and working fine. problem is i have to reload smarty variables value.